# How to remove "search web" option for selected text iOS 16 xcode14 beta

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, ios16, xcode14

I'm having trouble removing this tick when text is selected, I've tried this:

```
class CustomUITextField: UITextField {
   open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
      return false
   }
}
```

which removes stuff like copy, paste etc, but doesn't seem to remove this new iOS 16 feature. Thankful for any help :)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try：

```
    - (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))  {
        if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
            [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuLookup];
        }
        [super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code to your custom subclass:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    builder.remove(menu: .lookup)

    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```